# PL/SQL - Conditional compilation based on calling schema?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to set some private methods to be conditionally visible, but only to one specific schema which houses my unit tests.

In my research I haven't been able to find a way that can achieve this. A package constant obviously won't work and the PLSQL_CCFLAGS don't seem to do the trick either.

What I really want to do is something like the following -

```
$IF USER = 'TEST' $THEN
    --all my various procedures that should be hidden from all other users
$END
```

I could also settle for the methods being conditionally available only if the current logged in user is my `TEST` schema, e.g. `SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') = 'TEST'`

Is there any way to achieve this? My databases are on Oracle 11g. I believe this may be beyond CC capabilities as it seems only one compiled version can exist on the database at one time, period. Wondering if I'm missing something though.

Comment: See if you can use something like this : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/c_wrap.htm

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamically generated package that contains Boolean constants based on the schema name.  Then reference that constant when creating other packages.

(This assumes you are creating your schema from version-controlled text files, then this first step can be easily inserted in the build script.  This approach won't work with the old-fashioned method of exporting and importing schemas.)

```
--Dynamically create a package to hold constants.
begin
    execute immediate
    '
create or replace package compilation_constants is
    c_make_public_for_unit_tests constant boolean := '
        ||case when user = 'TEST' then 'true' else 'false' end||';
end;
    ';
end;
/

--Example of calling the constant package.
begin
    $IF compilation_constants.c_make_public_for_unit_tests  $THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('make them public');
    $ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('keep them private');
    $END
end;
/
```

You could theoretically save a step by dynamically-generating all the package specifications.  But that would require duplicating the `case when user = 'TEST' ...` check, and would also make all of your package files look ugly.  In this case it is worth creating a separate object in order to keep your other objects clean.